# Some services are not able to be constructed with blazor server

Tags: c#, constructor, blazor, blazor-server-side, blazor-webassembly

i have **class CustomersService : ICustomersService**

with constractor:

```
public CustomersService(HttpClient http)
{
   this._http = http;
}
```

and in **program.cs file**:

```
builder.Services.AddScoped<ICustomersService, CustomersService>();
```

How should I reboot/reset the constructor?

> builder.Services.AddScoped<ICustomersService, CustomersService>();
> the error is:

**InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'System.Net.Http.HttpClient'**

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/implement-resilient-applications/use-httpclientfactory-to-implement-resilient-http-requests

AddScoped -> AddHttpClient ?

Comment: You never registered HttpClient

Comment: exactly! That's the question, how to register? @ 
Panagiotis Kanavos

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you're in Blazor Server as the `HttpClient` is registered by default in Web Assembly.

Here's how I do it in Server:

```
// Server Side Blazor doesn't register HttpClient by default
// Thanks to Robin Sue - Suchiman https://github.com/Suchiman/BlazorDualMode
if (!services.Any(x => x.ServiceType == typeof(HttpClient))
{
     // Setup HttpClient for server side in a client side compatible fashion
     services.AddScoped<HttpClient>(s =>
    {
       // Creating the URI helper needs to wait until the JS Runtime is initialized, so defer it.
       var uriHelper = s.GetRequiredService<NavigationManager>();
       return new HttpClient
       {
          BaseAddress = new Uri(uriHelper.BaseUri)
       };
   });
}
```